# Is there a function for finding location of a object in a route after a specific time in R studio

Tags: r

I have just started to use gmap distance package in R studio.
I do not know how to compute the latitude and longitude of an object that moves with constant speed after a specific time. for example, an object starts to move from point A to B with constant speed. I want to know where the object (latitude and longitude) is after 5 mins.

Comment: This would be a much better question if it came with a reproducible example. Do you have the starting location's latitude and longitude? How is the route encoded - is it along roads from a mapping API, or a straight line between points? If a straight line between points, are you needing to consider great circle shortest paths, or are local approximations close enough?

Comment: I have the latitude and longitude of starting and ending points(A, B). It is along roads from a mapping API. I want to know where the object is after a specific time along the route on the map.

Answer (score 0):

consider the following sample data

```
points <- data.frame(id = LETTERS[1:2], lon = c(4.5,5), lat = c(52,52.5))
#   id lon  lat
# 1  A 4.5 52.0
# 2  B 5.0 52.5
```

This looks like

```
library(sf)
library(mapview)
library(data.table)
library(geosphere)
points %>%
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("lon","lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  mapview::mapview()
```

[image]

Now, the calculation. Let's sya you travel in a straightline from A to B, with a speed of 20 metres/second and want to know your position after 1200 seconds.

```
#get angle bewteen point A and point B
pA <- c(points$lon[1], points$lat[1])
pB <- c(points$lon[2], points$lat[2])
bearing.ab <- geosphere::bearingRhumb(pA, pB)
# [1] 31.47534

# Calculation of new position along bearing from A >> B
speed <- 20   #metres/second
time  <- 1200 #seconds
pAB <- geosphere::destPoint(pA, b = bearing.ab, d = time * speed)
#           lon      lat
# [1,] 4.683214 52.18382
```

To present, merge with the original points

```
new.points <- data.table::rbindlist(list(points, data.frame(id = "C", pAB)), fill = TRUE)
#    id      lon      lat
# 1:  A 4.500000 52.00000
# 2:  B 5.000000 52.50000
# 3:  C 4.683214 52.18382

new.points %>%
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("lon","lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  mapview::mapview()
```

[image]